# Center footer at the bottom of the page

Tags: html, css, footer

I am trying to place a footer at the center bottom of my page. I have the following css and html but I can't figure out a good way of doing it. Currently the issue is that the footer falls outside of the screenview on loading. Hate that and I think it has to do with the fact that the footer has position:flex. But I set "absolute" it gets messed up (see 2nd picture).

css

```
body {
  background-color: white;
  margin-top:3em;
  margin-bottom:3vw;
  margin-left:12vw;
  margin-right:12vw;
  font-family:Georgia;
  font-size:1em;
  color: #4D4D4D;
  }

hr {
    margin-bottom:3vw;
    margin-top:10px;
    height:0.08em;
    border-width:0;
    color:#231F20;
    background-color:#231F20;
    opacity: 0.2
}

a:link {
  color: #0168DA;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size:1em;
}

ul {
  font-family:Georgia;
}

h3 {
  margin-block-end: 0em;
}

p {
  margin-block-start: 0.5em;
  margin-block-end: 0.5em;
}

img {
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-bottom: 4em;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 480px) {

        body {
          margin-left:17vw;
          margin-right:17vw;
          }
    }

/* other */

.menu {
  padding-top: 3em;
  margin-bottom: 5em;
}

.right {
  text-align: right;
}



/* footer */
.footer-basic {
  padding:40px 0;
  margin-top: 16em;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  color:#4b4c4d;
  bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.footer-basic ul {
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:15px;
  line-height:1.6;
  margin-bottom:0;
}

.footer-basic li {
  padding:0 10px;
}

.footer-basic ul a {
  color:inherit;
  text-decoration:none;
  opacity:0.8;
}

.footer-basic ul a:hover {
  opacity:1;
}

.footer-basic .copyright {
  margin-top:15px;
  text-align:center;
  font-size:13px;
  color:#aaa;
  margin-bottom:0;
}

.list-inline {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.list-inline > li {
    display: inline;
    margin: 0;
}
```

html

```
html>
<head>

{% load static %}


</head>

<body>
  <p align="center">
    <span style="color:#B02E25;font-size:1.5em;">A Month At A Time</span>
  </p>

<div>
  <img width="150" height="94" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/giaggi/image/upload/v1613837471/amonthatatime/images/general/calvinandhobbes.png">
</div>


{% for post in latest_posts %}
<div class="post">
  <h3> {{post.title | safe}}
    <br> <span style="opacity:0.6; font-size:0.8em">{{post.month | safe}} {{post.year | safe}} </span>
  </h3>
  <p style="opacity: 0.7;"> {{post.whatsapp | safe | truncatewords:50 }} </p>
  <div class="right">
    <a style="color:#B02E25;" href="/amonthatatime/{{post.year}}/{{post.month}}/" target="">Open</a>
  </div>
</div>
<hr>
{% endfor %}

<div style="position:flex; bottom:0.5em;">
  <div class="footer-basic">
          <footer>
              <ul class="list-inline" style="margin:3px" >
                  <li class="list-inline-item"><a style="font-family:Georgia;color: #0168DA;" href="/amonthatatime/subscribe">Subscribe</a></li>
              </ul>
              <!-- <p class="copyright">A month at a Time</p> -->
          </footer>
      </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: At the last `div` try `style="position: absolute; bottom:0;"` instead of `style="position:flex; bottom:0.5em;"` . Also `position: flex` is a wrong CSS. Remove `margin-top: 16em;` from `.footer-basic`.

Comment: I doesn't work. The footer gets moved all on the left. (see updated question text+image)

Comment: Can I ask exactly what you're trying to do? Do you want the footer to always be at the bottom (like sticky) or to be pushed to pushed below the content and at least as far down as the bottom edge of the screen? Do you just want the word 'subscribe' centered at the bottom, or will you eventually have a larger footer (I see you have a list in the html)? Do you have a design for how you want it to look?

Comment: I want the word "subscribe" to be pushed down at the bottom of the page. Not sticky. Right now I only have one word but if I where to have 2 words or 3 words I would like them to be on the same line and pushed at the center (like a text-aling:center) bottom of the page. Does this makes sense?

So it's basically the first screenshot...but the word should be on the screen not outside of it because that's the end of the page...But that was a hack i did using margin-top...doesn't really put the footer at the bottom, just push it down a little bit. If the browser changes high it gets messed up

Answer (score 0):

I hope's the result goes acording you're need's

You can use this, i just change the next CSS lines:

```
.footer-basic {
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin-top: 1em;
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: white;
    margin-top:3em;
    margin-bottom:3vw;
    margin-left:12vw;
    margin-right:12vw;
    font-family:Georgia;
    font-size:1em;
    color: #4D4D4D;
    }
  
  hr {
      margin-bottom:3vw;
      margin-top:10px;
      height:0.08em;
      border-width:0;
      color:#231F20;
      background-color:#231F20;
      opacity: 0.2
  }
  
  a:link {
    color: #0168DA;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size:1em;
  }
  
  ul {
    font-family:Georgia;
  }
  
  h3 {
    margin-block-end: 0em;
  }
  
  p {
    margin-block-start: 0.5em;
    margin-block-end: 0.5em;
  }
  
  img {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-top: 1em;
      margin-bottom: 4em;
  }
  
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  @media only screen and (min-device-width: 480px) {
  
          body {
            margin-left:17vw;
            margin-right:17vw;
            }
      }
  
  /* other */
  
  .menu {
    padding-top: 3em;
    margin-bottom: 5em;
  }
  
  .right {
    text-align: right;
  }
  
  
  
  /* footer */
  .footer-basic {
    padding: 10px 0;
    margin-top: 1em;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    color:#4b4c4d;
    bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .footer-basic ul {
    padding:0;
    list-style:none;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:15px;
    line-height:1.6;
    margin-bottom:0;
  }
  
  .footer-basic li {
    padding:0 10px;
  }
  
  .footer-basic ul a {
    color:inherit;
    text-decoration:none;
    opacity:0.8;
  }
  
  .footer-basic ul a:hover {
    opacity:1;
  }
  
  .footer-basic .copyright {
    margin-top:15px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:13px;
    color:#aaa;
    margin-bottom:0;
  }
  
  .list-inline {
      list-style: none;
      padding: 0;
  }
  
  .list-inline > li {
      display: inline;
      margin: 0;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <p align="center">
        <span style="color:#B02E25;font-size:1.5em;">A Month At A Time</span>
    </p>

    <div>
        <img width="150" height="94"
            src="https://res.cloudinary.com/giaggi/image/upload/v1613837471/amonthatatime/images/general/calvinandhobbes.png">
    </div>


    <div class="post">
        <h3> {{post.title | safe}}
            <br> <span style="opacity:0.6; font-size:0.8em">{{post.month | safe}} {{post.year | safe}} </span>
        </h3>
        <p style="opacity: 0.7;"> {{post.whatsapp | safe | truncatewords:50 }} </p>
        <div class="right">
            <a style="color:#B02E25;" href="/amonthatatime/{{post.year}}/{{post.month}}/" target="">Open</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>

    <div style="position:flex; bottom:0.5em;">
        <div class="footer-basic">
            <footer>
                <ul class="list-inline" style="margin:3px">
                    <li class="list-inline-item"><a style="font-family:Georgia;color: #0168DA;"
                            href="/amonthatatime/subscribe">Subscribe</a></li>
                </ul>
                <!-- <p class="copyright">A month at a Time</p> -->
            </footer>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: mmm not really doing what I need. Here subscribe jumps up...I would like it to stay down at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

So one way to achieve this, would be to add a fixed height to your footer and then a min-height to your content. Something like this:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

main {
  min-height: calc(100vh - 4rem);
}

footer {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 4rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
      <p>Main content goes here</p>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <p>Subscribe</p>
    </footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

This just relies on the main content filling up the majority of the page, and 'pushing' down the footer to the bottom. The major con with this method is that you need to set a height on your footer, which may or may not be fine for your needs - that way you can se the height of the main section to `calc(100vh - 4rem)` where `100vh` is the the entire height of the page, less the height of your footer, in this example I made it `4rem` (but you could make it whatever you like).

I didn't bother putting all your code in there, but I hope you can work it out from here.

Make sure to use `min-height` on your content, so that it can grow as you have more content.

Comment: didn't work. On mobile web the subscribe it's still outside of the screen.

Comment: How did you test this? It works for me. Don't test it using the snippets here, because once you switch chrome to mobile, the screen size will change but the 100vh value won't update, and you can't refresh the page without losing the snippet being run.